How to fix "Correlation failed" exception, when using Microsoft.Identity.Web alongside with IdentityServer4?
Trying to use Microsoft.Identity.Web solution to make an external provider connection in Asp.net Core application.
I've connected it, using next C# code:
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

It integrates ok, as External provider.
However, when I log in, using current provider, I got an exception

System.Exception: 'An error was encountered while handling the remote login.'
InnerException.
Exception: Correlation failed.

As I researched, I found out that is it "Correlation cookie" problem (means the provider, won't find cookie to "correlate" with"). As I checked,

Request.Cookie.Count == 0

but Browser sends .AspNetCore.Correlation and .AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect.Nonce cookies with "N" value.
Application's cookie configuration setup are:
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
        {
            config.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;

           
        });
        services.ConfigureExternalCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "Identity.Application";
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        });

...
        app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions()
        {
            MinimumSameSitePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Lax,
            HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.None
        });

What's wrong with setup? May be something's wrong, or absent?
UPD: Cookie Setup added due to IdentityServer4 usage and customization. As I found out, Microsoft.Identity.Web adds own cookie scheme, not using Default one. So, correlation Cookie won't pass, cause different cookie scheme used (Request.Cookies.Length = 0). So, those one remains in conflict. Nevertheless, this question should stays opened, may be there will be some update, that fixes this issue, or my conclusions are wrong.

Could you pls let us know why you add those "Application's cookie configuration setup"?

@TinyWang, that was due to increase cookie Security levels. Tried to comment all it out, and nothing works...

I can reproduce your issue.

Just comment this line MinimumSameSitePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Lax,, then this issue will disapper.
In my humble opinion, we don't require to set the cookie policy. You can take a look at the Azure AD samples, no cookie policy is set.   Only builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd")); is required.

Tried your options... Unfortunatelly, didn't work. Also, commented all configuration out - no effect...

Additionally, got the next error in logs
"fail: 2024-09-24 15:15:59Z Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler [15 (CorrelationCookieNotFound)]
'.AspNetCore.Correlation.YrEsw2Bgd_AUL_6JY5Oyv2wxhHy0nb-aV_J8JuvaCOc' cookie not found.
info: 2024-09-24 15:15:59Z Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler [4 (RemoteAuthenticationFailed)]
Error from RemoteAuthentication: Correlation failed.."

I'm sure there's something wrong within your configuration. My test is based on a new .net 8 MVC project which is created by VS, and I choose the authentication type as Microsoft identity platform, then I will get all the configurations ready in the app, I just need to modify the appsettings.json file with the Azure AD value. Could you pls take a try in your side, then compare your configurations and the newly created project? It won't cost much time, and it will also let you know what configurations are necessary.

If you don't want to do it, could you pls share the document you followed to integrate Azure AD into your application? I'm still confused why you are trying to add so much cookie configurations into your application.

In fact, those was due to IdentityServer4 usage on current application. So, I suspect, that it conflicts each other, cause /signin-oidc scheme won't get cookies from request at all... When I call AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp with "cookieOptions" action, it won't callbacks it at all...

This looks to make sense. You already chose Azure AD and the identity provider, why you also use identityserver4?

That was due to solve another problems, not connected to external providers... Any way, thank you for your answers.

Thank you for the confirmation. And I think we already localize the issue.

Great! Should I expected an update?

Oh sorry, I'm not an expert on identityserver4, so that I can't provide suggestion for the extra cookie configurations.

Could you please hint, where to find the problem in IdentityServer4? May be I'll find a way to change that behavior outside

I think you might create a new question about ideneityserver 4 containing the requirement to manage the cookies, so hat you could get attention from this forum.
